# virtual cell mirror reflections

Tags: geometry, reflection

Please note that this is an extension of this question:
[Mirror reflection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86493/mirror-reflection)
[image: http://i.imgur.com/ALUdyoB.png]

**Questions**

Mirrors A and B with the space between them, including the bird, are part of the real world.
Those are all a part of a basic cell.

The space between A and B' (including the mirrored bird) is the mirror image (in mirror A) of the basic cell. This is a virtual cell space. we call this a virtual cell.

1. Add more virtual cells (mirror images of mirrors and repeats thereof) with
   birds in them.
2. Which structure or pattern do you discover in the of cells?

**My try**

1. Is this the correct way to do mirror reflection? You have to keep in mind that " If look at a mirror from the same direction and angle as one of the two arrows that are drawn, you will see the bird in the mirror." from the question [Mirror reflection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86493/mirror-reflection).

   [image]
2. I do see this repeating patterns, but I do not whether this has a specific name or not. Does somebody have a good way to describe it?

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86493/2451